# Cannot import MetaTrader5 python lib

Tags: python, metatrader5

I am using Python 3.8.2 on Windows 11. When I try to import MetaTrader5:

```
import MetaTrader5
```

I got errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MetaTrader5
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MetaTrader5\__init__.py", line 257, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: The specified module could not be found.
```

Could you please explain for me and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by importing more:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
```